# SQLBulkCopy Don't Copy Primary Keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

What is the best way to deal with the primary key violation errors when using SQLBulkCopy

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'email_k__'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object  'lntmuser.email'.
```

(i.e. if the row already exists in the destination table) ?

Is there a way to skip inserting duplicate rows or would this have to be checked and dealt with before hand ?

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
  var conPro = tx_ProConStr.Text;
  var conArc = tx_ArcConStr.Text;

  var con = new SqlConnection {ConnectionString = conPro};
  var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.email", con);
  con.Open();

  var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
  var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conArc) {DestinationTableName = "dbo.email"};

  sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);

  sbc.Close();
  rdr.Close();
  con.Close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually end up performing a Bulk Copy operation to a temporary table, and then copy data from it to the target table using regular SQL. This allows me to perform 'bulk updates', as well as take care of special situations like this (although I haven't encountered this specific need).

There's a performance hit compared to straight bulk copy, but it's still a lot faster than performing INSERTs.

Comment: +1 You could [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) the temp table with the destination table

Comment: Wouldn't a MERGE delete records from the destination table if they're not in the temporary table?

Comment: You can specify what the merge does; if you don't `when not matched by target then delete`, the rows will remain.

Comment: @zmbq I think this is the best solution given the problem, thanks also andomar the merge is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the source query to exclude duplicates.  For example:

```
select distinct * from dbo.email
```

Or to filter for the first `col1` per `pkcol`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (parition by pkcol order by col1) as rn
        from    dbo.email
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

Comment: I don't think the duplicates exist in the source table. OP was worried about duplicates in the destination table (because it's not empty).